Trying to add correlation test to plot using stat_cor
I am trying to get my correlation test results to show up on my ggplot. I looked it up and it seemed like stat_cor from the ggpubr package seems like the solution for this. I can not get it work however. Any help appreciated as to why it is not working.
Here is the code I am using for the plot
DailyAvgTempSiteL5_TailwaterGaugePlot <- 
  ggplot(DailyDownGaugeAvg, aes(Date, DailyGaugeHeightAvg)) +
  geom_line(
    data = DailyDownGaugeAvg,
    color = "blue")

  ggplot(L5DownDailyMerge, aes(Date, NULL, color())) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = Date, y = DailyAvgL5Temp), alpha = 0.25) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = DailyAvgL5Temp, color = "L5")) +
    
    geom_smooth(aes(x = Date, y = DailyAvgDownstreamGaugeTemp, colour = "Tailwater Gauge"), alpha = 0.25) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = DailyAvgDownstreamGaugeTemp, colour = "Tailwater Gauge")) +
  
    stat_cor(data = c(DailyAvgL5Temp, DailyAvgDownstreamGaugeTemp), method = "spearman") +
    
    scale_colour_manual("",
                       values = c("L5"="blue", "Tailwater Gauge"="red")) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    xlab('Date') + ylab('Daily Average Temperature (Celcius)') +
    ggtitle("Daily Average Temperature
Site L5 vs Tailwater Gauge")

This is the error showing up when run
Error: object 'DailyAvgL5Temp' not found

Here is the data I am using. I am new to r so asking lots of questions to try and figure out everything. I am sure I am doing something wrong but just don't realize what it is. Thanks for the help.
dput(head(L5DownDailyMerge))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19791, 19792, 19793, 19794, 
19795, 19796), class = "Date"), DailyAvgL5Temp = c(9.98765502929687, 
9.884833984375, 8.01781209309896, 8.70198394775391, 9.21991678873698, 
9.69807739257812), DailyAvgDownstreamGaugeTemp = c(7.965625, 
7.64673913043478, 8.63645833333333, 9.146875, 9.4375, 9.89895833333333
), DailyGaugeHeightAvg = c(9.34770833333333, 12.2685869565217, 
15.6577083333333, 16.4609375, 16.4171875, 15.7817708333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

